# ColdFusion Builder 3 vs. Dreamweaver & local and remote paths

Tags: eclipse, iis, coldfusion, development-environment

I can't wrap my head around how I'm supposed to use ColdFusion Builder 3 (akin to Eclipse).

Up until this point, I've been using Dreamweaver 5, which is getting 'long-in-the-tooth', and I wanted to give CF Builder a try.

So, in Dreamweaver, it's pretty simple: you setup connections to servers using credentials...  There's a Local path, which is the local copy of your code, and the webroot of the Server which is the 'live' copy of your code.  Basically, you make a change to the local copy, and PUT the change to the Server.  Easy peasy lemon squeezy, right?

But, how does this translate to ColdFusion Builder 3?

Just to give you an idea of our infrastructure.... we have Development and Production.  Each of these boxes has multiple web instances, example: Accounting, Human Resources, IT.  Each of those web instances could have multiple applications.... I'm only considered about my instance, IT, on both the Production and Development servers.

- Is a workspace supposed to represent an instance on a web server?
- In CFBuilder, should I configure 1 server per web app?
- Is a project supposed to represent a web app?
- Am I supposed to use drive mappings to the inetpub wwwroot for access to web applications?  Is it even considered kosher to have a drive mapping to the web root?  \server\c$\inetpub\wwwroot
- Where do I keep my local copy of my code?
- How do I move items from Development to Production?

My main confusion is with workspaces, projects, and servers...  My intent is to debug and 'view page in browser' from CFBuilder....  However, when you setup a server, under Server Mapping and URL Prefix, you're supposed to indicate the Local and Remote paths, plus this is not directly related to the physical location of the project.... and as I've mentioned, there's multiple instances, multiple applications, and the development box is not my local machine, it's a remote server...

I would really like to know how others have made this work for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't mind this question even though it's not directly code related because I've been using ColdFusion Builder (CFB) for years and there just isn't enough good documentation out there.  I now enjoy a great experience with CFB thanks to blog posts and sharing experiences with other devs :)

My setup: CFB3 running on Windows 8.1, dev server running on a Virtual Machine so it is treated as "remote server" just like yours.  I also update remote staging and production servers (although not directly from CFB).

First, let's set some reasonable expectations: Dreamweaver and CFB are very different in that CFB focuses on programming and Dreamweaver on design.  CFB is built on eclipse and therefore has the advantage of benefiting from most eclipse plugins.

Your question is specifically about how to set up your projects in CFB using 2 remote servers (dev and prod).  It's different for everyone but I'll share my setup with you.  (sidenote: My projects are also stored in Git repositories - 1 repo for every app)

Starting from the top: A workspace in CFB deals with your whole eclipse application, not just your projects.  The most important things kept in this directory are snippets and plugins. You do NOT need to keep your project files in here.  This is merely the main directory where all of your settings are kept.  You are not required to have more than 1 workspace (I only have one).  Why would you need more than one? You may be multifaceted programmer who needs to keep separate workspaces using separate tools (like different plugins, snippets, window layouts...)

To answer your next question (1 server per web app), all you need to to is configure your dev servers in the "CF Servers" tab.  You need to add 1 server per web instance for every instance that you'd like to test on.  Hopefully, your dev server has RDS enabled (very helpful for remote database and file viewing, just like in Dreamweaver).  During configuration, don't worry about Mappings or Virtual Host Settings (I have another recommendation later).  Once configured, you'll be able to assign that server to a project.

Drive mappings: I would never recommend mapping to the webroot of a shared dev server. If you were to use that drive map as your local directory, your changes will be made directly to the development server.  What you want to do is create a new project by right clicking in the Navigator area and select **Import > Other > FTP**.  Follow the steps, choose anywhere on your local drive to store the files, then choose "New project" at the end (this will add the .project file necessary for CFB to control the project).

Once the project is created, right click on it, select ColdFusion Project and choose the CFML Dictionary version you'll be using (CF11, 10, 9...).  Then, select ColdFusion Server Settings and choose the dev server.  This is necessary for testing.

What you now have is a local directory with your app and eclipse knows about the remote server.  In order to synchronize, you right click on the project, go to Team and synchronize from there.  For detailed information about synchronization over FTP, see the help section "Guide to WebDAV and FTP".

Moving to production is not as simple as it was in Dreamweaver.  The FTP configuration information only allows for 1 connection (thus giving you a list of files synchronized between your project and the dev server).  Therefore, you'll need a third party FTP client to synchronize between your local project and your prod server.

As promised, my last entry will be able the "debugging" which is why I said to skip the mappings and virtual host settings in CF Server config.  I really, really recommend using a third party paid plugin called FusionDebug (http://www.fusion-debug.com/).  This plugin facilitates the setup and allows you to step-into all of your code (which doesn't work so well in native CFB).  There's a 30 day trial and I recommend you try before your buy (or license for a year in this case!)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions, and put some things into context, it helps me move forward tremendously.